# Is using <div>'s with display:inline-block often bad practice?

Tags: html, css

Whenever I'm creating a page with a horizontal component, most of the top-level elements are usually div's where I set display to inline:block. For example:

```
<div id='header'>
    <div class='inline_block'> stuffff </div>
    <div class='inline_block'> stuffff </div>
    <div class='inline_block'> stuffff </div>
</div>

#header{width:100%}
.inline_block{width:20%; display:inline-block;}
```

This always achieves what I want it to, but it feels *wrong*. Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

Comment: Why does it feel wrong?

Comment: No. It's excellent and most useful

Comment: It's good if you know how to use it.

Comment: No way. Divs are naturally block-level elements, but that doesn't mean they can't be changed. There aren't any (to my knowledge) naturally inline-block-level elements, so this is a perfect use. A div is just a standard container of elements.

Comment: @Itay, Constantly changing the default display of an HTML element made me feel like I was using it incorrectly.

Comment: I would personally rather use floats (although, depending on the circumstance, you might not be able to). When you specify a div (or any element) as display: inline-block, any single whitespace in your markup after the element matters and elements can have spaces between them. If you say { display: block; float: left; }, whitespace in your markup is ignored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The div element has no special meaning at all.
>
> Authors are strongly encouraged to view the div element as an element
>   of last resort, for when no other element is suitable. Use of more
>   appropriate elements instead of the div element leads to better
>   accessibility for readers and easier maintainability for authors.

[Source](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-div-element)

In practicality, most sites use `div`s heavily, and that's fine. However, HTML5 adds new tags which *do* have a meaning (and even HTML 4 has tags which may be more appropriate, such as `li`, `dl`, etc.)

It is the user agent which implements the display characteristics a `div`. All browsers apply a default style of `display:block` (the same way as the user agent uses `display:inline` for `spans`). Contrary to other answers/comments I've seen, `inline` [is not the same](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-display) as `inline-block`, so just swapping `spans` for `divs` will not give the same behavior.

In certain cases, it makes complete sense to alter the display of select `divs` to `inline:block`. It's a useful behavior.

Is there a "better" element? Perhaps, but that decision should be based on properly structuring the document, not the default style assigned by the browser.

More importantly, ensure that you are using semantic markup and CSS that makes sense (using a class name of "inline-block" is not a good idea; if you change the corresponding CSS to something else, the name is now wrong).

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with using inline-block, but I would question it if you are using classes like inline-block.  You want to use more meaningful class names and if those classes need to be set to inline-block, that is fine.  In your example, if all immediate child divs are to be inline-block, you can do it like this:

```
#header > div {
   display: inline-block;
   *display:inline; //IE7
   *zoom:1; //IE7
}
```

One thing to note is that in IE7, inline-block doesn't work as expected unless hasLayout is triggered, which you can do with zoom:1.